# Will My Harddrive be erased when i replace my windows 10 with ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, installation

I Have an acer Nitro 5 Laptop currently running windows 10 but I want to install ubuntu on it
it has a 256GBSSD(Which is the boot drive) and A 1TB Hardrive(which stores my files) if I Install ubuntu by replacing windows 10 will my files in the harddrive get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive data (with the Windows file) would get erased and the Ubuntu files would overwrite it. Not sure how your hard drive would get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The anwer is: it depends!

The ubuntu installer does generally not delete your data and if it does, it warns you before doing so.
BUT: errors happen! If you want to be on the save side, physically unplug your harddisk with the data before installing a new operating system.

Comment: Thanks  I will Backup my data(Its Easier than unplugging)